# Meteor & account-base - how to get data for different users

Tags: meteor, user-accounts

I have basic project in Meteor created from Meteor-admin stub: (https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin)

I need to display avatars for all users, not only current one.
For displaying user's avatar I need his email address. (I am using utilities:avatar https://atmospherejs.com/utilities/avatar)

**Question:** what adjustments to project should I make to be able to access other users' data?

It probably has something to do with publishing users.

At the moment I have:

```
{{> avatar user=getAuthor shape="circle" size="small"}}         

getAuthor: ->
  console.log 'Owner:'
  console.log @owner
  user = Meteor.users.findOne(@owner)
  console.log user
  user
```

This correctly prints `Owner: @owner` (id) for all users, but `user` object is only populated for current user.

I also have this code in server-side:

```
Meteor.publishComposite 'user', ->
  find: ->
    Meteor.users.find _id: @userId
  children: [
    find: (user) ->
      _id = user.profile?.picture or null
      ProfilePictures.find _id: _id
    ]
```

(children / ProfilePicture are irrelevent)

I think `account-base` library turns publishing off or something? Thanks for help!

**Bonus question:** I would like to access only some info about an user (email address).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the package `autopublish`, you need to specify explicitly what the server sends to the client. You can do this via `Meteor.publish` and `Meteor.subscribe`.

For instance, to publish the email addresses of all users you could do:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('emailAddresses', function() {
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {
            fields: {
                'email': 1
            }
        });
    });
}
```

After that, you need to subscribe to the publication on the client:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("emailAddresses");
}
```

Read more about [Meteor's publish and subscribe functionality](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe).

Answer (score 0):

Having collection: `Meteor.users`

To access other users data just publish it on the server-side:

```
Meteor.publish 'userData', ->
    Meteor.users.find()
```

On client side you don't have to use any `userData` reference. Just access it:

```
Meteor.users.findOne(someId)
```

To allow access to only specific information, publish it with `fields` parameter:

```
Meteor.publish 'userData', ->
    Meteor.users.find({},{fields: {'_id', 'emails', 'username'}})
```