# Meteor: How can I make my app recognize other messages from other users

Tags: meteor, chat, messaging

I have created a messenger app. When the users sign in, they can select who to chat with. However, when they start chatting. It only recognizes the user who is signed in and not the other chatter. Here is a screenshot of what I mean. I am signed in as a user from firefox and another from chrome. Any examples would be great, thank you. Im pretty new at this :)

[image: Here is a screenshot.]

Here is my Template

```
<template name="chat_message">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <img src="/{{avatar}}" class="avatar_img">
            {{getUsername _id}} said: {{text}} 
        </div>
    </div>  
    <br>
</template>
```

My helper

```
Template.chat_message.helpers ({
    getUsername:function(userId){
      user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userId});
      return Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile.username;
    },
    avatar:function(userId){
      user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userId});
      return Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile.avatar;
    } 
  });
```

Server

```
Meteor.publish("chats", function () { 
      return Chats.find(); 
    });

    Meteor.publish("messages", function () { 
      return Chats.find(); 
    });

    Meteor.publish("userStatus", function() {
      return Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true });
    });

    Meteor.publish("userData", function(){
      return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
    });

    Meteor.publish("users", function(){
        return Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true })
    });

  Chats.allow({
    insert: function () { return true; },
    update: function () { return true; },
    remove: function () { return true; }
  });

  Meteor.methods({
    sendMessage: function (chat) {
      Chats.insert({
        chat: chat,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        username: Meteor.user().profile.username,
        avatar: Meteor.user().profile.avatar,
      });
    },
```

Comment: By default, Meteor only publishes logged-in user's data (from Meteor.user collection) to the client. This means you can't access the other user's data from the client side, unless you publish them explicitly.

Comment: This is what I have published. Should I add something else?

Comment: Added the server side above.

Comment: Yes, your publications are correct. Make sure you are subscribed to the correct publication. More info at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31607876/meteor-account-base-how-to-get-data-for-different-users).

Also, `return Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile.username` will always return the logged-in user's data. Instead use `Meteor.users.find()`

Comment: replacing to meteor.users.find() gave me a broken image and [object Object] for the username. Not sure why.

Comment: Try something like `meteor.users.find({_id: other_users_id}).fetch()[0].profile.username`. Basically, find() returns a cursor, which we convert to an array of objects using fetch(). And then we select the first object (there is only 1 object).